# Modelling a scenario involving art exhibitions

Tags: database-design, schema

Saffron Gallery is about to host an exhibition next month. A number of works of art (paintings, sculptures, etc.) will be exhibited.

**Business rules**

- Every art work will have a barcode, a title and a description.
- Each art work is created by a single artist.
- Every artist has a name, an address and a contact
  number.
- One artist may create more than one art work for the exhibition.
- People will come and visit the exhibition.
- As each person enters the exhibition, their name, address
  and phone number will be recorded.
- Each person will be given a unique barcode id.
- During their visit, people will nominate which art work they consider the best and this will be
  recorded by Uptown Gallery.
- People will be able to vote for more than one art work.

**The task and my current considerations**

I have to find elements (entities, attributes and relationships) of relevance in this business environment.

To me, the tables should be structured as follows:

- Art work

  - Barcode (Primary Key)
  - Title
  - Description
- Artist

  - Name
  - Address
  - Contact no
- People

  - Name
  - Address
  - Phone number
  - Barcode (Primary Key)

Just want to know if I am correct or not?

Comment: I guess you've started on the right path, but obviously are far from done. You're missing entities (visitor's votes) and relationships (e.g. between the artists and their artwork).

Comment: in which table I supposed to put them.

Comment: what should be the attributes of visitors vote and can you define relationships?